# PostgreSQL: заменить ' на " в строке

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.

Мне нужно заменить ' на " в строке.

Делаю так:

```
UPDATE 
        source_redshift.staticprompts
    SET 
        inputs = REPLACE(inputs,''','"')
    WHERE
        prompttype = 'input' AND (created > now() - interval '30 minutes' OR modified > now() - interval '30 minutes');
```

но полуячаю ошибку форматирования в месте REPLACE(inputs,''','"'). Не могу понять как правильно сформировать запрос. Можете помочь?

Comment: `REPLACE(inputs,'\'','"')`

Comment: Пробовал так. Но ошибку выдает [42601] Unterminated identifier started at position 91 in SQL UPDATE source_redshift.staticprompts SET inputs = REPLACE(inputs,'\'','"') WH ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил так:

```
UPDATE
        source_redshift.staticprompts
SET
        inputs = REPLACE(inputs, '''', '"')
WHERE
        prompttype = 'input' AND (created > now() - interval '30 minutes' OR modified > now() - interval '30 minutes');
```